# necessary and sufficient conditions for a function to be DC

Tags: ca.classical-analysis-and-odes, convexity, global-optimization

Hi, Does anyone know the necessary and sufficient conditions for a function to be a DC-function?

Definition: A function is a DC-function if and only if it can be written as a differnece of 2 convex functions.

Answer (score 2):

For real functions whose domain is a real interval, it is necessary and sufficient that the second derivative is a function of bounded variation on every compact interval in the domain.
Or, in terms of distributions, the second derivative must be a measure (a difference of two non-negative
measures).

Comment: This is for real-to-real function only.

Comment: $x \: \mapsto \: x^4-0 \;\;$ seems like a counterexample to the necessity. $\;\;\;\;$

Comment: Yes, this was for functions R to R. Concerning the counterexample,
I edited the statement:-)